# Concerning what is between two consecutive squares.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is there a  squarefree ( with two prime divisors) betweem any two consecutive squares?

Comment: What does 2-almost prime mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it has been proved that there is always a prime or semiprime between consecutive positive perfect squares. See [Chen, J. R. "On the Distribution of Almost Primes in an Interval." Sci. Sinica 18, 611-627, 1975.](http://math.scichina.com:8081/sciAe/fileup/PDF/75ya0611.pdf)

Comment: Can two consecutive squares have no semi-prime between them?

Comment: Well there is no semiprime strictly between $1$ and $4$.

Comment: Can infinitely many pairs of consecutive squares have no semi-prime between them?